# Apache/mod_jk module fail to connect jboss after running some time

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jboss

I use [Apache/mod_jk module](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-connectors.cgi) to connect jboss. But after running some time, something goes wrong .

Apache:  2.2.22
mod_jk: 1.2.37
Jboss: 5.1.0 GA(cluster environment)
OS: CentOS 5.2 x86_64
JDK: 1.6.0_30-b12

Here is some part of mod_jk.log

```
[Thu Oct 18 15:21:35.044 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1035): (node1) cping/cpong after connecting to the backend server failed (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:21:35.044 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (node1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:22:35.643 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1035): (node1) cping/cpong after connecting to the backend server failed (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:22:35.643 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (node1) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:22:35.643 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2626): (node1) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Thu Oct 18 15:23:36.143 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1035): (node2) cping/cpong after connecting to the backend server failed (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:23:36.143 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (node2) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:24:36.742 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1035): (node2) cping/cpong after connecting to the backend server failed (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:24:36.742 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1630): (node2) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=110)
[Thu Oct 18 15:24:36.742 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2626): (node2) connecting to tomcat failed.
[Thu Oct 18 15:24:36.742 2012] [26272:47208100643936] [error] service::jk_lb_worker.c (1485): All tomcat instances failed, no more workers left
```

part of http.conf:

```
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkMountFile conf/uriworkermap.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel warn
```

workers.properties:

```
 worker.list=loadbalancer,loadbalancer_2,status
 worker.node1.port=8009
 worker.node1.host=10.123.76.6
 worker.node1.type=ajp13
 worker.node1.lbfactor=1

 worker.node2.port=8009
 worker.node2.host=10.123.76.4
 worker.node2.type=ajp13
 worker.node2.lbfactor=1

 worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
 worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1,node2

 worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=true
 worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session_force=false

 worker.loadbalancer_2.type=lb
 worker.loadbalancer_2.balance_workers=node1,node2
 worker.loadbalancer_2.sticky_session=true
 worker.loadbalancer_2.sticky_session_force=false
```

**Attentions**: Jboss is working fine.  `telnet` jboss `8009` is normal. If you restart jboss, it works again. But if you restart apache, it doesn't help。

Anyone has ever encounter this problem ?

Comment: why you set two identical loadbalansers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think setting connection timeout for ajp connector would fix your problem.
Setting like this should work

```
<Connector port="8009" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3"
         emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="1000" connectionTimeout="60000000" />
```

you configure this in server.xml

more documentation on this attribute you can read about in official docs http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/ajp.html

Comment: Excuse me, What is the meaning of `connectionTimeout` ?

Comment: check http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/latest/config/ajp.html
connectionTimeout:
The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait, after accepting a connection, for the request URI line to be presented. The default value is infinite (i.e. no timeout).

It can happen that connection "hangs" and wont timeout and that will fill the connection pool (controlled by max-threads) after connection pool is full, it will wont accept any new connections and server would "stale"

Answer (score 1):

Did you set correct jvmRoute in server.xml file?

```
jboss-as/server/${profile}/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml
```

exact line should look like this:

```
<Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="node1">
```

and on the second server there will be jvmRoute="node2".

Answer (score 0):

Please troubleshoot the issue as below.
1. Hit the URL from different browsers without restarting the webserver.(If its not working Below solution will work for you)

Please check in both JBoss configuration must have 8009(AJP) port enabled. In your case there are two instances in two different physical servers.  must have the mentioned port configuraed. Its a default setting. Check whether it is changed or not by mistake. Basically this is corresponds to http offset 0.